# Как сделать что бы размер card был одинаковый в зависимости от соседей?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

**Например в одном блоке больше текста чем в другом**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 **как подтягивать остальные блоки** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20288%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_168e1ed6549%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_168e1ed6549%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2296.8359375%22%20y%3D%22118.8%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20288%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_168e1ed6549%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_168e1ed6549%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2296.8359375%22%20y%3D%22118.8%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer. This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20288%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_168e1ed654a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_168e1ed654a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2296.8359375%22%20y%3D%22118.8%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, но в принципе, это не правильно. Если цепляете бутстрап, то лучше пользоваться его возможностями. Правда тут не смогу помочь.

```
.row,
.row>.col-md-4 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте следующие классы - `d-flex` и `align-items-stretch`

Пример

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20288%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_168e1ed6549%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_168e1ed6549%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2296.8359375%22%20y%3D%22118.8%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20288%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_168e1ed6549%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_168e1ed6549%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2296.8359375%22%20y%3D%22118.8%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer. This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little
            bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20288%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_168e1ed654a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_168e1ed654a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22288%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2296.8359375%22%20y%3D%22118.8%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```